# How can I continuously replace an element of an array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

At each time step, I am trying to replace one element of my `list` with the sum of the other 2 plus 1. This is my code:

```
def replace(x, y, z):

    for i in range(3):

        rep_x = [y+z+1, y, z]
        rep_y = [x, x+z+1, z]
        rep_z = [x, y, x+y+1]

        ini_x = rep_x
        ini_y = rep_y
        ini_z = rep_z

    return ini_x, ini_y, ini_z


print replace(2, 4, 6)
```

This gives me a single line - a one-time replacement. I would like the code to keep doing the replacements on the newly-obtained arrays every time, for example:

([11, 4, 6], [2, 9, 6], [2, 4, 7])
((11, 4, 6], [11, 18, 6], [11, 4, 16]), ([19, 9, 6], [2, 9, 6], [2, 9, 12]), ([12, 4, 7], [2, 10, 7], [2, 4, 7]))

How can I do this?

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the indentation, and exactly how many times do you want the replacement to be done?

Comment: Trying 3 times for now, but I might want to change it to more later.

Comment: so as it loops 1st time it gives `( [11, 4, 6], [2, 9, 6], [2, 4, 7] )` for `x, y, z = 2, 4, 6` respectively, that understandable. But as it loops second time, what do you want the new `x, y, z` values to be?

Comment: I want the new x, y, z values to be the values obtained in the 3 arrays (and iterate over each of them). For example here I want them to be 11, 4, 6 (iterate over this), then 2, 9, 6 (then iterate once over this), then 2, 4, 7 (then iterate over this), and so on. Does that make sense?

Comment: I posted an Answer, although I am still not able to completely understand. But my Answer matches yours so, check it out.

Comment: follow this [link for instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this helpful:

```
def replace(x, y, z):
  ini_x = [y+z+1, y, z]
  ini_y = [x, x+z+1, z]
  ini_z = [x, y, x+y+1]
  return ini_x, ini_y, ini_z


s = replace(2, 4, 6)
print s
for i in s:
    print replace(i[0], i[1], i[2])
```

output:

```
([11, 4, 6], [2, 9, 6], [2, 4, 7])
([11, 4, 6], [11, 18, 6], [11, 4, 16])
([16, 9, 6], [2, 9, 6], [2, 9, 12])
([12, 4, 7], [2, 10, 7], [2, 4, 7])
```

Comment: Yes, this works for the first few steps! How can I modify it to keep doing the same thing (on the newly obtained arrays) every time?

Comment: well, the function returns only 3 arrays, so no matter what, we can only iterate it 3 times, right.

Answer (score 0):

> at each time step, replace one element of my array with the sum of the other 2 plus 1

```
from __future__ import print_function
def business(array): # Can't give a proper name without knowing what the function does
    total = sum(array)
    return [total + 1 - x for x in array]

arr = [2,4,6]
steps = 10
print(arr)
for step in range(steps):
    arr = business(arr)
    print(arr)
```